# Is there any point in close voting questions as off-topic?

Tags: discussion

By looking at the woocommerce tag It doesn't seems like closing woocommerce related questions removes them from the site as the oldest was closed two years ago and it is still around - [Woocommerce Add Variation Product to Cart from custom link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/86967/woocommerce-add-variation-product-to-cart-from-custom-link). It is nice that "I am moderating WPSE" but it doesn't feel like that the boring game of going over the review queue actually yields any result as the number of WC related questions do not decrease and I would assume that is is because the good SEO SE has for the old questions.

IMO woocommerce tags questions should be closed automatically or at least require some reputation to pst them, at least it will give a strong indication to the people posting them that they are unlikely to get an answer even if they try to game the system. For other plugins it is possible to construct similar honeypots if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions with accepted or upvoted answers does not get deleted by the system if they are closed or have been *without significant activity* like @Rarst said. Questions with**out** upvotes or upvoted/accepted answers does get deleted after a period (*normally a year*) regardless of being closed or not. Really poor quality questions (*questions with significant downvotes  and which also might have downvoted and unaccepted answers*) are removed like in a week after being closed although I'm not very clear on the exact time period

Users who have 20K+ reputation like myself can delete questions, but here is the catch (*Taken from [this page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)*)

- Voting to delete questions with a score of -3 or lower immediately after they are closed

So for a normal community member like me to delete a question, a question needs

- 3 downvotes
- 3 delete votes, so a question would need two other 20K+ reputation users to vote on such a question

So, in short, the privilege you get at 20K+ is still just a carrot and meaningless on a stack like this. If you currently remove the 6 mods, we are really really less than a handful members with 20K+.

To be honest, the complete system is quite crappy. I've been taken to the sword a few times due to my downvoting, but this is forced by the system. Even a moderator have told me to be kind with new users. The system **REQUIRES** me to downvote to vote to delete a question or answer (*only when the quality of the answer/question is bad and does not deserve to continue to exist*), which is just totally against the so called be nice policy of the SE network.

- Voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower
- Voting to delete questions with a score of -3 or lower immediately after they are closed

So, what @Rarst have said, *leaves it up to humans* leaves me with this, the system needs us to be harsh and rude to moderate the site if we are not moderators. That is why I now rarely dowwnvote and cast delete votes (*accept still on answers which does not qualify as an answer*). These so called nice privileges we get is really nothing to be proud off or to get all happy about.

Are we really, like you said, *I am moderating WPSE*

As for the plugin tags like woocommerce, it will never work as you have indicated

> IMO woocommerce tags questions should be closed automatically or at least require some reputation to pst them,

- First of all, not all woocommerce questions are off topic. Some (*OK, very few exist*) are answerable within a general scope. I have answered questions tagged with the woocommerce tag that does not even need the woocommerce tag.
- The huge (now dead) debate about which questions should be on topic and which not
- Almost all new users incorrectly tag their questions, take the php, wodpress.com and wordpress.org tags. Almost all new users simply ignore or do not care to read tag descriptions before using a tag. If a tag remotely resembles the content of they question, they use it. This causes a lot of incorrect tagged questions. If you are going to give the system automatic closing abilities due to tag, this will cause quite a lot of stir.
- New users will simply tag their question with any tag just to post a question if they do not have enough reputation to post a question in a specific tag. This happens daily with answers. New users simply post questions or comments or anything else as answers because they do not enough reputation to post comments. Even though the system genereates a message when the post a new "answer", it is simply ignored. A new user will do anything to *game* the system, wrong tagging, posting any crap in the answer section, etc etc

There is really nothing we can really do about this, we are not moderators, we are users with filthy moderator privileges. If we really need bad questions removed ASAP, we still need to closevote, **downvote** (*which does not really fit the be nice policy*) them, and then we still need three delete votes from 20K+ reputation users. If we cannot do that, then we simply have to wait for the system to eventually delete them, if some other users haven't given sympathy upvotes to these questions, in which case it might never be deleted

Comment: The suggestion of honeypot is because people just don't know it is off-topic as no one reads the tag description and those that bother reading the help probably don't get the distinction between plugin specific question and one that is not. It is actually a time waster for the people that ask the questions, especially the ones that bother to add code so I actually don't really think that leaving them open for days until they get 5 close votes is being nice, but oh well I didn't really think it is something that is actually possible right now.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember closed questions *without significant activity* on them do get deleted by system after a while.

Unfortunately there aren't really any nice solutions to enforcing the scope. Computers aren't good for it, leaves it up to humans. So yeah, boring it is. :)

Comment: Actually disagree with "computers aren't good with that" as auttomated antispam systems do work with low rate of false positives.

Comment: Mark Kaplun if antispam systems actually worked no one would ever spam again since it would be completely pointless to. Spam filtering is clunky best effort, abundant with false positives. It's a valid choice to prioritize quality manual moderation over crappy automated one.

Comment: Disagree. People send spam because it is cheap so why not to use it. In israel it seems like a combination of "everybody uses antispam" and raising the price of spam by sueing the spammers resulted in zero spam in my mailbox, and my email address is freely available on my hebrew blog so it must be in all the relevant spamming list ;). Phising is different because the gain is much higher then just selling one more product and there are always idiots that believe they should go over their spam bucket to make sure there wasn't an important message from paypal.